# Getting some stuff in output of the C program

Tags: c

For coding I am using the Visual Studio Code. I have written the code to calculate the distance of the marathon also in that code I have taken some values from the user but after taking the values from the user the remaining code is not working and I am unable to get the output.

The code is below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

int miles, yards;
double kilometers;

printf("Enter the miles distance:\n");
scanf("%d",miles);

printf("Enter the yards distance:\n");
scanf("%d",yards);

kilometers = 1.609 * (miles + yards / 1760.0);
printf("\nA marathon is %lf kilometers\n\n",kilometers);

return 0;

}
```

After taking input from the user as:

```
Enter the miles distance:
26
Enter the yards distance:
385
PS D:\C language\C FOR EVERYONE_PROGRAMMING FUNDAMENTALS\WEEK 1>
```

Can you please tell me Why I am not getting the output that I want.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings and read a good C book. You're not using `scanf` correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both the `scanf()`s you have given the value instead of the address. Try this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int miles, yards;
    double kilometers;

    printf("Enter the miles distance:\n");
    scanf("%d", &miles);

    printf("Enter the yards distance:\n");
    scanf("%d", &yards);

    kilometers = 1.609 * (miles + yards / 1760.0);
    printf("\nA marathon is %lf kilometers\n\n",kilometers);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
scanf("%d",miles);
scanf("%d",yards);
```

with

```
scanf("%d",&miles);
scanf("%d",&yards);
```

scanf wants the **&** symbol before variable names (all type of variable except strings)

---

EDIT: As Tortellini said in the comment, I could have explained the reason why this happens

The reason is simple, look at this:

```
int var = 3;
printf("%d", var); //It prints 3
setToZero(var);    //Function that sets its parameter=0
printf("%d", var); //Stil prints 3
```

In this example, you create a COPY of variable's value: If the value in the function changes, you will able to see the changes inside that function only

Using the & symbol, you won't create a copy: you will just tell to the function the memory address where to find the original variable value

If the function changes the value of the variable, all the changes will also be shown outside the code.

Using "scanf" function, you want to let the function overwrite the value of your variable as you want to use it after. For this reason, you need to write the **&** before the variable's name

Comment: sorry & thank you to you..sorry because I have not carefully observed the program due to that I have caused the trouble for you, i have already written the correct program in notebook but at the time of writting in code editer, I forgot to insert the address of the variable i.e."&" and thank because you find out my mistake and solved it.